# Meaning of the phrase ובחנם דחק לפרש in Tosofos

Tags: talmud-gemara

I'm seeing a phrase ובחנם pop up in Tosofos in a few places, for example ובחנם דחק לפרש on [בבא קמא נת עב](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Bava_Kamma.59b.13.1?vhe=Vilna_edition&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

Curious if anyone knows what that means.

Comment: For no reason he did give an improbable explanation, it's to say, he was thinking that there is a kashia and he forced himself to give an explanation far from the simple sense

Comment: Ah I see the meaning of חנם in that context, thanks. If you write your post as an answer I would accept it if you want the points

Comment: @kouty So the speaker thinks the subject _didn't_ have a good reason for giving the non-pshat answer, although obviously the subject himself did? Or is the speaker saying 'because of his kasha he answered that way'

Comment: you can also upvote

Comment: @kouty unfortunately I don't have the reputation for it but would love to!

Comment: @kouty if you have a chance to answer my clarifying question above I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For no reason he did give an improbable explanation, it's to say, he was thinking that there is a kashia and he forced himself to give an explanation far from the simple sense because the speaker has an okimta regarding the timing of the situation.

Anyway, there is always a choice between two dochakim. But the speaker prefers to maintain a simple pshat in the text.